# How to change book language in Google Play Books

Tags: languages, dictionary, google-play-books

Does anyone know how to change the language of a book in Google Play Books?

I uploaded a portuguese book (epub) to Google Play Books, but when I highlight a word, the app does not recognize that the word is in portuguese and returns me the definition as if it is an english word.

When I buy a portuguese book from Google Play it works properly, but not for uploaded files.

The epub file language is correctly set to Portuguese.

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: This problem goes even further. If you want to let android read it aloud TTS always uses the "english voice". This problem only occures with uploaded ePub files.